# SQL. Select statement with a added 'yes' or 'no' column answer acts weird

Tags: sql, select, case

I have two tables with traffic accidents. These tables are from different databases. These tables are `P_TRAFFIC_2015` and `SPV_TRAFFIC_2015`. The only relationship between this tables is the column `Routenumber`.

To compare the accidents from this tables I have compare the `roadnumber` and the date and time of the accident. I do this with the SQL statement below. In the result of the select statement I want see every row of the `P_TRAFFIC_2015` table with a added 'yes' or 'no' column. If this accident matches with a row from the `SPV_TRAFFIC_2015` table, it should be a 'yes', else 'no'. I could be that multiple rows are matching, in that case I don't want to see multiple rows, it just must be a 'yes'.

```
 select 
     PV.TRAFFIC_2015_NR,PV.DATE_AND_TIME,
     case 
        when PV.ROUTENUMBER = SPV.ROUTENUMBER 
             and DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PV.DATE_AND_TIME, SPV.DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN -60 AND 60 
           then 'YES' 
           else 'NO' 
     end
 from
     P_TRAFFIC_2015 PV, SPV_TRAFFIC_2015 SPV
 group by 
     PV.TRAFFIC_2015_NR, PV.DATE_AND_TIME,
     case 
        when PV.ROUTENUMBER = SPV.ROUTENUMBER 
             and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,PV.DATE_AND_TIME,SPV.DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN -60 AND 60 
            then 'YES' 
            else 'NO' 
     end
order by 
    1
```

But with this `SELECT` statement I get the weird thing when the answer is 'yes' the `SELECT` query also shows the same record with a 'no' answer. So I see to many records.

When I use a join in the FROM (below) not all the rows from the P_TRAFFIC_2015 are shown. So I see to little rows.

```
FROM 
    P_TRAFFIC_2015 PV 
INNER JOIN 
    SPV_TRAFFIC_2015 SPV ON PV.ROUTENUMBER = SPV.ROUTENUMBER
```

Please help!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should clarify as why you are using `group by` in your query? don't see any reason for using it.

Comment: I did that because else I see every row like ten times in the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing join conditions.  However, I think the best approach is a subquery in the `select`:

```
select pv.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from SPV_TRAFFIC_2015 spv
                          where PV.ROUTENUMBER = SPV.ROUTENUMBER and
                                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PV.DATE_AND_TIME, SPV.DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN -60 AND 60 
                         )
            then 'YES' 
            else 'NO' 
        end) 
from P_TRAFFIC_2015 PV;
```

This has several advantages over a `join`:

- No `group by` is needed in the outer query.
- It is easier to select more (or all) the columns from `pv`.
- The logic is quite explicit about the nature of the flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to include a `JOIN` (included a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` considering that there may not be all matching records)

```
SELECT 
    PV.TRAFFIC_2015_NR, PV.DATE_AND_TIME,
    CASE 
       WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PV.DATE_AND_TIME, SPV.DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN -60 AND 60 
          THEN 'YES' 
          ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS computed_column
FROM 
    P_TRAFFIC_2015 PV
LEFT JOIN 
    SPV_TRAFFIC_2015 SPV ON PV.ROUTENUMBER = SPV.ROUTENUMBER
GROUP BY
    PV.TRAFFIC_2015_NR, PV.DATE_AND_TIME
ORDER BY 
    1
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer! Unfortunately your answer doesnt work. I still get the same results as with my SELECT statement. So it returns to many rows.